# No graph plotted in output using python

Tags: python, vpython

I have a code and I want to see output using vpython.
following is the code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ python3
from vpython import *
Plot1 = gcurve ( color = color . white )
for x in arange(0., 8.1, 0.1):
        Plot1.plot( pos = (x, 5.*cos(2.*x)*exp(-0.4*x)) )

graph1 = gdisplay ( width =600, height =450 ,\
        title="Visual 2D Plot", xtitle="x", ytitle="f(x)",\
        foreground = color . black , background = color . white )
Plot2 = gdots ( color = color . black )

for x in arange( -5., +5, 0.1 ):
        Plot2.plot(pos = (x, cos(x)))
```

it is giving this error, however, it is showing a box of a white background with no plot in it.
Error: name 'gdisplay' is not defined

how can I define g display?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the visual module of VPython:

```
from visual.graph import *
```

Comment: it is not working      from visual.graph import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visual'

Comment: visual was the name of the module many years ago but is now vpython, and as noted here before, the graphing machinery is now named "graph", not "gdisplay".

Answer (score 0):

With VPython 7 the name is "graph", not gdisplay. And "from vpython import *" includes the graph object.